How to change selected image's rendering order in Unity?
I have a grid layout group and under that multiple images. What I want to achieve is that whenever I select (click and start dragging) an object, I want its rendering order to be prior so that because of the hierarchy it won't go behind its siblings. How can I achieve this in Unity?
Here is my code:
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DragAndDrop : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    private RectTransform selfRectTransform;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private int originalSortingOrder;

    private void Start()
    {
        selfRectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        canvas = GetComponentInParent<Canvas>();
        originalSortingOrder = canvas.sortingOrder;
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // Increase the canvas sorting order to render the object above others
        canvas.sortingOrder++;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        selfRectTransform.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // Restore the original canvas sorting order
        canvas.sortingOrder = originalSortingOrder;
    }
}

Setting order settings in the Layer Section in Editor.

For the ones who experience the same issue, I found a solution as follows:

I created a duplicate of the draggable images parent inside the same parent
I wrote a controller for the parent which keeps the references of these two image children
When I start dragging, I deactivated the draggable list and opened the other parent so that the non-draggable objects remain as they are and set active false the dragging object in the second list

Basically it works in a way that a temporary holder keeps the images and when I start dragging I deactivate the draggable items' parent and activate the temporary one so that draggable image goes in front of the non-draggable ones by closing the clicked object in temporary list.

I think you are on the right track , what i think is missing maybe is inside your OnBeginDrag function, i think instead of canvas.sortingOrder++ you should use originalSortingOrder + 1, this is to handle it more accurately
canvas.sortingOrder = originalSortingOrder + 1;


I also tried this but the problem is that it still behaves in the same way. I don't know whether it is because I didn't define orders in the layer settings or something else but it does not behave as expected.

Just a recommendation, whenever you deal with layers it is a lot better to have some layer configuration and Canvas setting to appoint to, Create Sorting layers, as many as you need and assing each UI element you have to a layer, additionally you can check the order and Canvas settings

Check if drag and drop is working properly.

The main camera must have a Raycaster.
The canvas to operate must be in "Screen Space - Overlay" mode
The object to be dragged and dropped must have a collider.
The code must be in the image object








Could you rename the image links, please?
